# How to prove an upper bound on polynomial $x + \sqrt{2} x^2 + \sqrt{3} x^3 + \ldots + \sqrt n x^n$

Tags: polynomials

If $P(x) = x + \sqrt 2 x^2 + \sqrt{3}x^3+\ldots + \sqrt n x^n$ how can I prove that if $x > 1$ then $$ P(x) \leq \sqrt {\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \frac{x^{2n+1}-1}{x^2-1}}$$

given that $ 1 + 2 + \ldots + n = n(n+1)/2$ and some geometric sum around with $x^2$ terms

Comment: This looks like Cauchy-Schwartz inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As didgogns pointed out, this is an application of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. The idea is as follows.
$$(\sum_{k=1}^n u_k v_k)^2\leq(\sum_{k=1}^n u_k^2)(\sum_{k=1}^n v_k^2)$$
Substituting $u_k=\sqrt{k}$ and $v_k = x^k$ gives you
$$P(x) \leq \sqrt {(\sum_{k=0}^n k)*(\sum_{k=0}^n x^{2n})}$$
And simplifying gives the sums you
$$P(x) \leq \sqrt {\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \frac{x^{2n+1}-1}{x^2-1}}$$